# How can I enter more than five values on one line?

Tags: kotlin, destructuring

I need to enter nine values on one line in Kotlin:

```
fun readInts() = readLine()!!.split(' ').map { it.toInt() }

fun main(){
    val (x, y, z, f, e, m, s, t, c) = readInts()
```

but when I try to do this, I get an error:

```
Error:(5, 30) Kotlin: Destructuring declaration initializer of type List<Int> must have a 'component6()' function
```

Thanks in advance for your help)

Comment: It's a list, not a 9-element tuple.

Comment: Any particular reason it needs to be on one line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kotlin only defines `component1()` through `component5()` on `List`, which it uses for destructuring, so that limits what you can do with it.

However, thanks to [Extension Functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html), we can define our own:

```
operator fun <T> List<T>.component6(): T = this[5]
operator fun <T> List<T>.component7(): T = this[6]
operator fun <T> List<T>.component8(): T = this[7]
operator fun <T> List<T>.component9(): T = this[8]
```

(And so on...)

And then this should work:

```
val (x, y, z, f, e, m, s, t, c) = readInts()
```

Note that this will probably fail as written if your components are null.